# How should I clean my dishwasher filter?

Tags: dishwasher

My dishes, especially glasses, are often getting dried sediment left on them after a cycle in the dishwasher.  I run it with vinegar every couple months but that doesn't seem to be enough.  I want to clean the filter and surrounding assembly similar to what's done in the YouTube video "Repair Dishwasher For Cleaner Dishes - Maintenance Clean Fix Whirlpool Kenmore" but can't tell how to access mine.  The plastic bolt in the very middle will turn and turn but not come out.

[image: bottom of dishwasher]

I've looked through the [manual](http://www.searspartsdirect.com/partsdirect/user-manuals/GU2275XTVY1-WHIRLPOOL-UNDERCOUNTER%20DISHWASHER-manual) and a RepairClinic “Troubleshooting” page that comes up when I google the model number, but they don't seem to be much help, unless I missed something from them.

Comment: are you using rinse agent? this product is designed for this purpose. Also, are you on city water? You can also try changing detergents. Regarding disassembly, I believe you center spinner clips/locks in. I would still google your model # for the service manual to be sure, but it either has a release or just lifts off. just be sure first so it doesnt get broken. then under that will be philips or star/torx screws to remove the filter cover. If you want to really clean it, you should go as far as the pump

Comment: Yes, I am using rinse agent, and yes, I am on city water.  I've used a few different detergents.  I'll look for the service manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some digging for you:
http://www.appliancerepair.net/dishwasher-repair-3.html

Here's the remove of the filter cover:
http://www.partselect.com/Models/GU2275XTVY1/Sections/PUMP-AND-MOTOR-PARTS/?ModelID=1619670&ModelNum=GU2275XTVY1&mfgModelNum=&ManufactureID=3&Selected=HALWT3WI&Position=9&mfg=Whirlpool&Type=Washer&Mark=9

Here's the arm parts:
http://www.partselect.com/Models/GU2275XTVY1/Sections/LOWER-WASHARM-PARTS/?ModelID=1619668&ModelNum=GU2275XTVY1&mfgModelNum=&ManufactureID=3&Selected=JY7US5YH&Position=7&mfg=Whirlpool&Type=Washer&Mark=7

So removal is righty loosey :)  DEFY THE RULES!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGZYhEljgPw

Good luck!!!